# How to animate a WinForms scroll

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, smooth-scrolling

I have a C# control that has an scroll.

When a user drag and drop, the scrolls are updated. I would like to animate the drag&drop movement like google maps does. The movement is smoothly animated.

What technique must I use if want to simulate a swipe in the control, and perform a smoothly animated?

Comment: winforms doesn't support animations, and it will not run "smoothly" because of the lack of hardware acceleration.

Comment: Yes, I want to implement it manually. Using a thread, a timer, and moving the scroll manually

Comment: Pretty unclear what you are talking about, Google maps doesn't use a scrollbar.  If you are talking about the swipe gesture with kinetics then you can get that from the built-in Windows multi-touch support.  A Winforms wrapper is [available here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsTouch/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2127), the .NET interop sample link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for was the easing equations: http://www.gizma.com/easing