# Smooth scrolling ListView C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, scroll

Is it possible to implement smooth (pixel) scroll in a `ListView` like how it works in `RichTextBox`? I used details `ListView`, `VirtualMod` `off`.

Comment: I think it's a duplicate of: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687140/how-to-animate-a-winforms-scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using [SourceGrid](http://sourcegrid.codeplex.com/) ([codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3531/SourceGrid-Open-Source-C-Grid-Control)) instead ListView.